# Как выводить информацию по отдельности из таблицы?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Пробовал с библиотекой pymysql выводить информацию с БД. Получаю информацию в виде таблицы, но выводить эту информацию через индексы не могу. Выводятся лишь символы.

```
with connection:
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(str(result))
```

Получаю:

```
{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Dmitriy_Makarov', 'Contact': 0}
```

Я пытался через индексы:

```
print(str(result)[0])
```

Но получил: `{`, то есть первый символ таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы указали `pymysql` возвращать **словари** в качестве строк данных:

```
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             database='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
#     NOTE: ------------->   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

то и обращаться к элементам словаря нужно соответственно - по ключам:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for row in cursor.fetchall()
        print("ID: {ID}, Name: {Name}, Contact: {Contact}".format(**row))
```